# Cancel UIGesture that already started iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

**What I currently have:**

I have a child `UIViewController` inside my main `UIViewController`. In this child `UIViewController` I have an `UITableView`, although anything can be inside of it (`UIScrollView`, `UIImageView`, composition of different `UIViews` sub-classes).

On my main `UIViewController` I have `GestureRecognizerDelegate`, so I am receiving callbacks when a gesture is made, like this:

```
- (void)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer movedWithTouches:(NSSet*)touches andEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

- (void)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer endWithTouches:(NSSet*)touches andEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@optional

- (void)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer beganWithTouches:(NSSet*)touches andEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

For a particular gesture done on top of the main `UIViewController`, I am showing a small `UIView` with an `UIImageView`. So basically when a touch is made from top to botton where the Y < 100 the UIView animates and shows the image and when I release my finger from the screen the `UIView` goes back to the top. It's pretty much like the notification center that Apple provides, except that I don't control the scrolling of it and it only shows for 200px from the top.

**The problem:**

In theory the `UIView` with the `UIImage` is the top-est `UIView` on my hierarchy, but when I keep moving around with my finger on it's area, I can see the `UITableView` underneath it, moving. For me it doesn't make sense since the `UIView` with the `UIImageView` should be capturing those gestures.

**What I want:**

Simply when I show the `UIView` with the `UIImage` disable all the interaction on that `childViewController`.

**What I have tried:**

Currently I have this:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

If I put to NO, the `UIView` with the `UIImage` doesn't even show.

If I put something like `myChildViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO`, since the gesture already started, it won't work. Of course if I use that before the gesture has started everything will work as intended. But the problem is that I won't be able to use the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end what's working is:

```
   -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // Check if I am not on the Default state (UIView with the UIImageView hidden)
    if(currentState != kDefaultState)
    {
        otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        [arrayOfDisabledGestures addObject:otherGestureRecognizer];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

When I finally close the `UIView` with the `UIImageView` I do the following:

```
[arrayOfDisabledGestures makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setEnabled:) withObject:@YES];
```

To re-enabled all the gestures. I don't really like the solution, I think there should be (and I bet there are) other ways of doing this.